# Common knowledge as a fixed point

Tags: logic, game-theory, fixed-point-theorems, modal-logic

I read on a wikipedia page that from the modal logic formalization CK can be formulated as a fixed point. If it also holds for the set theory formalization? If it does, where I can find about it?

**Edited:** Common knowledge is used to be thought about like a limit of "I know that you know that I know that you know that I know..."

A nice example is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge_%28logic%29).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is also a set-theoretic formulation of common knowledge as a fixed point. Common knowledge of an event $E$ is the greatest fixed point of the function $f_E(X)=K^1(E\cap X)$, where $K^1(Y)$ denotes first-order mutual knowledge of $Y$, i.e., that everyone knows $Y$. The existence of a greatest fixed point is guaranteed by the [Knaster–Tarski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem). You can read about this account of common knowledge in the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/common-knowledge/#2.4).

Comment: Thank you, bounty worked )